# Trying to take stock data and graphing it, but is stuck with this error

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, stock

```
import yfinance as yf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

amd = yf.Ticker("AMD")

print(amd.history(period="10y"))

def graph_data():
    source_code = str(amd.history(period="10y"))
    stock_data = []
    split_source = source_code.split("\n")
    for line in split_source[2:-1]:
        stock_data.append(line.split())
    del stock_data[-1]
    stock_data = str(stock_data)

    date, openp, hihgp, lowp, closep, volumep, div, splits = np.loadtxt(stock_data, delimiter=",", unpack=True)
    print(date)


graph_data()
```

I get these errors for some reason, and is wondering if any of you know what I'm doing wrong:

> `line 18, in graph_data
>       date, openp, hihgp, lowp, closep, volumep, div, splits = np.loadtxt(stock_data, delimiter=",", unpack=True)
>   line 968, in loadtxt
>       fh = np.lib._datasource.open(fname, 'rt', encoding=encoding)
>   line 269, in open
>       return ds.open(path, mode, encoding=encoding, newline=newline)
>   line 623, in open
>   raise IOError("%s not found." % path)
>   OSError: [['2009-11-30', '6.90', '7.01', '6.78', '7.01', '19388300', '0', '0'], ['2009-12-01', '7.11', '7.25', '7.01', '7.20', '23136400', '0', '0'], ['2009-12-02', '7.21', '7.50', '7.21', '7.30', '26906700', '0', '0'], ['2009-12-03', '7.37', '8.23', '7.36', '8.03', '69019800', '0', '0'], ['2009-12-04', '8.09', '8.25', '7.65', '7.86', '43885500', '0', '0'], ['...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...'], ['2019-11-21', '40.42', '40.71', '38.64', '39.52', '88069400', '0', '0'], ['2019-11-22', '39.36', '39.89', '38.19', '39.15', '56931900', '0', '0'], ['2019-11-25', '39.50', '40.17', '39.49', '39.79', '45769500', '0', '0'], ['2019-11-26', '39.30', '39.48', '38.81', '38.99', '43603300', '0', '0'], ['2019-11-27', '39.46', '39.76', '39.07', '39.41', '33630100', '0', '0']] not found.`

Comment: Use `pandas` dataframes to load the data and plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.loadtxt` takes a path to txt file as input. It will open the file and read the content from there. You already have `stock_data` as an array, why convert it to string and read back? You can do, for example, after the `for` loop:

```
date, openp, hihgp, lowp, closep, volumep, div, splits = np.array(stock_data).T

print(date)
```

Output:

```
array(['2009-11-30', '2009-12-01', '2009-12-02', '2009-12-03',
       '2009-12-04',...], dtype='<U10')
```